Problem Launching App After Upgrading from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.2.11
I am having trouble upgrading a repository from spring 2.7 to 3.X My app builds fine but when I go to launch it I get the same error message every time. I have tried adding, removing, updating various dependencies but no dice. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening and how I can fix it?
My Lombok file is up to date, my java version is 17. I can't remember everything I have tried as I have been working on this for some time, but I have tried going through and systematically deleting and testing all of my spring starters, as well as adding and removing various logback packages.
I also found this thread about the issue that claimed the problem was fixed in spring boot version 3.3, but I have tried 3.3.0 - 3.3.6 and had the same error in all of them. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/42432
I did start over from scratch at one point and saw that the error was introduced as soon as I changed the spring boot starter parent version, but I am using the managed version of all of my other starters.
Thank you very much and any help would be appreciated.
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: configurationLock
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:364)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.stopAndReset(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:243)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:189)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:149)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:195)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:77)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at X.main.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/util/StringUtil
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.extractThreadName(LoggingEvent.java:229)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.getThreadName(LoggingEvent.java:210)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.prepareForDeferredProcessing(LoggingEvent.java:300)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:235)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:102)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:85)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:272)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:259)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:426)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:386)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:780)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLocationAwareLog.error(LogAdapter.java:431)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:859)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:814)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352)
    at X.main.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:28)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.StringUtil
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 24 more

Here is my pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.5</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <groupId>X.match.recommendations</groupId>
  <artifactId>X-recommendations-svc</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>X-recommendations-svc</name>
  <description> recommendations service spring boot app</description>
  <repositories>
  </repositories>
  <properties>
    <rest.assured.version>3.3.0</rest.assured.version>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Default connection pool dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Swagger UI -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring starters-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- batch job scheduler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring cloud dependencies for openfeign client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Json data processors -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20240303</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jakarta-xmlbind-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Kafka & Streams-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Database Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-63</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jupiter API for writing tests -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test coverage report -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Presto DB-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
      <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>0.289</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Elastic Search DB-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
      <artifactId>yasson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.json.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.json.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Logging Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
      <!--Reporting Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--prometheus metrics-->
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2023.0.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!--Plugins for test coverage reports-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.12</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Maven plugin to use particular java version to compile code -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>


Why on earth are you managing dependencies that are managed by the Spring Boot starters, that beats the whole purpose of those starters not to mention you will/might endup with a mix of incompatible jars. You are basically working around the framework. I would start by cleaning up the dependencies that are already managed. I think the main culprit is the logback-jackson as that depends on an old version of logback, probably pulling in incompatible versions. As stated cleanup and then run a mvn dependency:tree so check versions.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Thank you for the suggestions. It is not logback-jackson that is causing the issue. I have removed it and am still experiencing the same error. I apologize for the long pom.xml with the issues you mentioned above. I did not write the application and it is complicated with a lot of moving parts, and therefore difficult to create a minimal reproducible example because I am unsure where the problem is, which is why I included the whole pom.

I updated my pom in the question. There were only a couple of things I was managing the version of manually that were already being pulled in by a spring starter.

Need more info. What IDE are you using? Are you building/running from the CLI? Your IDE could be caching your pom and build configuration and not updating when you edit the POM.

I am using Eclipse with Spring Tools. I have deleted the .mvn folder and rerun all installations with a terminal instead of the IDE. I have also cleared the IDE's cache and reinstalled and made no progress. I have tried building and running through both the terminal and IDE.

Update: I had someone clone this repo into their local environment and it worked perfectly fine for them. So I recloned and it is launching. It was some kind of caching going on causing the error from the IDE is my guess. Thanks for the help everyone!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
